# Flash Caurina Tween to MOV or MPG4

Tags: flash, actionscript, tween

I have to create a video for a company by projecting via usb on a 1920x1080 monitor. 
For the animation I have to use flash, and for convenience I wanted to use Caurina Tween. 
How can you export a file to quicktime mpg4 or using animations via script?

thx

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Flash Professional to build SWF, just go to Publish settings and select MOV as an output format.